# How to setup babel 7 config files with Electron two package.json Structure?

Tags: electron, babeljs, babel-loader

I am upgrading to Babel 7. They have changed how config files are loaded.
As much as I've tried per their docs I can not make it work. [Babel config loading docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#config-loading-options)

An Electron app with two package.json structure is explained here:
[Electron builder docs](https://www.electron.build/tutorials/two-package-structure)

The problem is it looks like my babel config is not being loaded for the code where the second package.json is located. (main renderer)

I tend to think that this is because of this new way of loading config and the two package.json but it could be something else.

The app structure looks like this:

```
/package.json
/.babelrc (or babel.config.js now)

/app/package.json
/app/main.js <-- this can not be compiled anymore
```

I use Webpack with the babel loader.
Somehow, with the Webpack dev server, it works, but compiling for production fails.

The exact error I get is this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
import "core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable";

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

For which I got [a clue here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8731#issuecomment-423845498) that made me think there is some config being ignored.

The entire project is open source and can be seen [in Github](https://github.com/AoDev/kaiku-music-player).
Cloning and running `npm run compile:main` will show the error.

Comment: Have you looked over https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files? A `babel.config.js` would likely resolve the issue. That error also sounds like you'll want to set https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype to something other than `module`.

Comment: I have tried to use a babel.config.js file but it still didn't pick it up. So I thought maybe it was my webpack babel-loader config that needed something, but passing options there like configFile didn't work neither.